# Extract subscript of variable in product

Tags: pattern-matching, output-formatting, factorization, indexed-variable

My input is a product of the variable `x` with index:

```
x[1]^2 x[5] x[7]
```

How do I extract the indices of the above product to get the list `{1,1,5,7}` as an output? Note 1 appears twice in the list since `x[1]` is squared.

I would like this code to work for any product of `x[j]^n`, where both j and n will be given integers.

Comment: `Cases[expr, x[i_]^p_. :> Table[i, p], {1}] // Flatten`

Comment: Thank you @BobHanlon.  Your solution is simple -- do you want to submit your comment as an answer?

Comment: Just wanted to say: good job avoiding `Subscript` and using indexed variables instead! This is the way to go! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
expr = x[1]^2 x[5] x[7];
```

Use [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) and include [`Default`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html) in the pattern for the exponent.

```
sol = Cases[expr, x[i_]^p_. :> Table[i, p], {1}] // Flatten

(* {1, 1, 5, 7} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to achieve it, decomposed step by step:

```
ClearAll[x];
p = x[1]^2 x[5] x[7];
f = FactorList@p
Table[First@#, Last@#] & /@ Rest[f]
Flatten@%
Block[{x = # &}, %]
(*
{{1, 1}, {x[1], 2}, {x[5], 1}, {x[7], 1}}
{{x[1], x[1]}, {x[5]}, {x[7]}}
{x[1], x[1], x[5], x[7]}
{1, 1, 5, 7}
*)
```

(there may be a better way of extracting `i` from `x[i]`...)